# Configuring ExtentReports to inject custom html

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, testng

I need my Extent Report (v 3.0.0) to have a hyperlink in the page. I am trying to inject the custom HTML for the following, where webSessionID is a UUID I scrape from the webpage.

The URL  format should be:

```
<a href="https://myapp.xmltravel.com/app/logs/s/OPY5Q2EV3P:6CBA845DB3E99F97931FCC9ED84711EB">OPY5Q2EV3P:6CBA845DB3E99F97931FCC9ED84711EB</a>
```

Here is what I am trying (note code comments for relevant areas):

My code:

```
public class TestBase implements Config {

protected WebDriver driver = null;
private Logger APPLICATION_LOGS = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
private static ExtentReports extent;
private static ExtentTest test;
private static ITestContext context;
private static String webSessionId;

@BeforeSuite
@Parameters({"env", "browser"})
public void beforeSuite(String env, String browser) {
    String f = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\test-output\\FabrixExtentReport.html";
    ExtentHtmlReporter h = new ExtentHtmlReporter(f);
    extent = new ExtentReports();
    extent.attachReporter(h);
    extent.setSystemInfo("browser: ", browser);
    extent.setSystemInfo("env: ", env);
    String codeBlockOne = "<a href=" + "\"https://myapp.com/app/logs/s/\"";
    String codeBlockTwo = "/a>";
    m1 = MarkupHelper.createCodeBlock(codeBlockOne); //SET HTML OPENING
    m2 = MarkupHelper.createCodeBlock(codeBlockTwo); //SET HTML CLOSING
}

@AfterMethod
public void afterMethod(ITestResult result) throws IOException {
    switch (result.getStatus()) {
        case ITestResult.FAILURE:
            test.fail(result.getThrowable());
            test.fail("Screenshot below: " + test.addScreenCaptureFromPath(takeScreenShot(result.getMethod().getMethodName())));
             test.fail("WebSessionId: " + m1 + webSessionId + m2);//RELEVANT METHOD
            break;
        case ITestResult.SKIP:
            test.skip(result.getThrowable());
            break;
        case ITestResult.SUCCESS:
            test.pass("Passed");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Current output of the relevant tag is:

```
    <td class='step-details'>WebSessionId:  
com.aventstack.extentreports.markuputils.CodeBlock@432038ectfbweb0~FE5625464A1F6ED331FB2355BDAF8F00com.aventstack.extentreports.markuputils.CodeBlock@7daa0fbd</ td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: Where in the page do you want to add this link?  In a test/log?  If log, simply do this: <code>test.info("<a href='https://myapp.xmltravel.com/app/logs/s/OPY5Q2EV3P:6CBA845DB3E99F97931FCC9ED84711EB">OPY5Q2EV3P:6CBA845DB3E99F97931FCC9ED84711EB'></a>
");</code>

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with ER but you are just getting string representation of Markup object reference. `m1 = MarkupHelper.createCodeBlock(codeBlockOne);` m1 will have `Markup` type. Try to use `m1.getMarkup()`.